# Check if specific values are already being displayed to the user via datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I used to present the information of specific inputs in a HTML table with this logic: the user has to complete six textbox(input type) in a form and then press the submit button in order to display the same info in six columns in a table HTML but before that I check that one specific input value is not in any row of my table... and works just fine, this is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                var cont=0;
            $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                cont++;
                var id = $("#inputText1").val().toLowerCase();
                var lastname = $("#inputText2").val();
                var name = $("#inputText3").val();
                var country = $("#inputText4").val().toLowerCase();
                var DUI = $("#inputText5").val();
                var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val();



                if (checkId(lastname)) {
                    return alert('El ID ya ha sido especificado');
                }

                $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td for="id">' + id + '</td><td for="lastname">' + lastname + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + country + '</td><td>' + DUI + '</td><td>' + ISSS + '</td><td><a href="#" id="select">Modificar</a></td></tr>');
                $("#inputText1").val('');
                $("#inputText2").val('');
                $("#inputText3").val('');
                $("#inputText4").val('');
                $("#inputText5").val('');
                $("#inputText6").val('');
                $('#inputText1').focus();

            });

            function checkId (lastname) {
                let ids = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td[for="lastname"]');

                return [].filter.call(ids, td => td.textContent === lastname).length === 1;
            }
```

but now I have started to like the Datatable jQuery and I have  populated a datatable with this code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                responsive: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/home/loaddata",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "pais", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": true },
                        { "data": "nombres", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "telefono", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "correo", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "dui", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "nit", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "defaultContent": "<button>editar</button>" }
                //{ "defaultContent": " <a href='#' id='select'>Modificar</a>  "}
                ],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sEmptyTable": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "sInfo": "Hay _TOTAL_ registros. Mostrando de (_START_ a _END_)",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Por favor espera - Cargando...",
                    "sSearch": "Filtro:",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sLast": "Última página",
                        "sFirst": "Primera",
                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    }
                } 
            });
        });
```

My question is: If I use two different inputs in order to let the user specifies the DUI and ISSS info, how could I check that the DUI and ISSS info in the inputs are not already displayed to the user via datatable jQuery?  I don't want to involve databases queries, just to check is the DUI and ISSS values are already specified in any row of the datatable, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides `search()` dataTables [**API**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) have a few utility methods you may find interesting, like `indexOf()`. However, I have the feeling you want to search for *exact* lowercased matches in the entire dataset.

Store the API reference by `var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({ .. })`

Then, by using dataTables `toArray()` and the magic of chaining you can check if a certain value is present by :

```js
table
  .data()
  .toArray()
  .toString()
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(',')
  .indexOf(value.toString().toLowerCase())>-1
```

You can place this in an external function returning `true` or `false`. Or more elegant [**`register()`**](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/api#Registering-a-new-method) a new function to the tables own API :

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'hasValue()', function(value) {
   return this
     .data()
     .toArray()
     .toString()
     .toLowerCase()
     .split(',')
     .indexOf(value.toString().toLowerCase())>-1
})
```

Now you can simply check if a value exists on the fly with

```
if (table.hasValue(something)) {
}
```

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4orohac9/**

Notice that `table.hasValue('regional')` returns false, `table.hasValue('regional marketing')` returns true: Exact matches on lowercased content and terms.

Comment: "on the fly" just exactly the word I was meaning for. just a question, this code as it seems is ready to use, is that correct or do I have to add something? and a second question, if I got the value for my input this way var lastname = $("#inputText2").val();  the call to the function will works this way: if (table.hasValue(lastname)) { ... } ?  just want to make that clear, thanks in advance

Comment: @PabloTobar, Eh, well, yes...? Why not try it yourself? :) BTW, you dont need to pass anything to a variable `if (table.hasValue($("#inputText2").val())) {` is sufficient.